# DataGridView Filter Not Show Rows

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview, filter, datatable

I searched the form but I could'ny find a solution my problem.
If I missed something, sorry about that.
My problem is; when I tried to filter my datagridview on the form, filter is working but my rows come empty.I tried to bound my datatable to another datagridview  and it worked.But I don't understand why it is not working my display gridview.

My Gridview and Test GridView Image :

[image]

And here is my code:

```
  //dt is a DataTable
  dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("My_Column_Name like '%{0}%'",
                                                txtSearch.Text);
   MyDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
  frm_Test frm = new frm_Tes(dt);//Another form for testing
  frm.Show();
```

I can see my datas in the test datagridview.So what I am doing wrong? Thank you for your helps.

Comment: When you write DataTable dt = new DataTable() you are creating an empty datatable with no rows. I wonder why applying a filter to an empty datatable doesn't throw an exception. Unless this is not your real code.

Comment: I am adding my rows and columns manually.I just did not write as a part of my question because that part is working well.I edit my codes